# How to estimate the dielectric constant of a liquid?

Tags: physical-chemistry, thermodynamics, molecules, theoretical-chemistry

Are there any approximate relationships between the (static) dielectric constant of a liquid and properties of the individual molecules?

For example, suppose I know the polarizability and dipole moment of a molecule, as well as it's density in the liquid phase. Can I estimate the dielectric constant of the liquid from these quantities (or other similar ones)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, such relations exist.

Notably there are two general theories for polar and non-polar fluids that connect the polarizability $P$ with the dielectric constant $\epsilon$ as reviewed in this article by [Harvey and Lennon, International Journal of Thermophysics, Vol. 26, No. 1, January 2005](http://www.nist.gov/mml/acmd/fluids_modeling/upload/Harvey-Lemmon-50062.pdf).

The Clausius-Mosotti equation for **non-polar liquids** is:
$$P = \frac{\epsilon-1}{\epsilon +2}$$

Whereas an equation developed by Kirkwood for **polar liquids** is:
$$ P = \frac{(\epsilon-1)(2\epsilon+1)}{9 \epsilon}$$

The article then continues to explain that you can estimate the polarizability from theoretical relations involving the molar density $\rho$ and the dipole moment $\mu$, but in your case the two equations above are sufficient since you assume that you know $P$.